# How to detect putting in or taking out headphones pausing video in Flash using AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, video, netstream, headphones

I've noticed the sneakiest behavior playing video with NetStream. If the video has an audio track, and the headphones are plugged in to my machine or removed, the video pauses for a second, and then the audio starts playing from the new output.

However, there's no way to listen for this happening that I can find! Flash certainly doesn't allow access to the client machine's sound card, so we can't talk directly to the system about this. Also, I've tried listening for NetStatus events from the NetStream that could inform me that the stream is pausing and then resuming, but no events are dispatched.

Does anyone know of an event I can listen for to capture this input switch? I was thinking of using an Event.ENTER_FRAME event to check the fps of the video every frame, or the time property of NetStream, but that seems pretty hackish.

Any better ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It's not netstream and not Flash Player, it's the device (sound card) pausing the sound during switching from headphones to speakers or vice-versa.